# x is not a function (selectvalue)

Tags: javascript

I'm making a script where I can change input value by clicking list-item with data-value and I'm just stuck and don't know there's a problem. When a list item is clicked there is an error in the console that "this.setSelectValue" is not a function.

```
  var FontSwatch = function (swatch, select) {
    this.swatch = swatch;
    this.select = select;
    this.bindEvents();
  };

  FontSwatch.prototype.bindEvents = function () {
    this.swatch.find('.swatch-item').on('click', this.handleSwatchClick);
  };

  FontSwatch.prototype.handleSwatchClick = function (e) {
    var target = $j(e.currentTarget);
    if (this.setSelectValue(target.data('value'))) {
      this.select.trigger('change');
      this.addSelectedClass(target);
    }
  };

  FontSwatch.prototype.setSelectValue = function (value) {
    return this.select.val(value).length === 1;
  };

  FontSwatch.prototype.addSelectedClass = function (selectedItem) {
    this.swatch.children().removeClass('selected');
    selectedItem.addClass('selected');
  };

  fontSwatch = new FontSwatch($j('.swatch'), $j('.font-select'))
```

Comment: `select` is a reserved word. I'd suggest calling that variable something else.

Comment: @LeeTaylor That’s not true. `select` isn’t a reserved word in JS and never was.

Comment: @Xufox You're right. Over tired here! I was thinking of `switch`. Interestingly enough SO's syntax colouring renders select differently!

Comment: @LeeTaylor That's because other languages have select as a reserved word :)

Comment: I'll get some sleep! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When jQuery calls an event handler, it sets the context to the event target. You need to bind the method to the `FontSwatch` object.

```
  FontSwatch.prototype.bindEvents = function () {
    this.swatch.find('.swatch-item').on('click', this.handleSwatchClick.bind(this));
  };
```

More generaly, using `value.functionName` as a callback does not bind the function to the given value. Context is only set when you use the `value.functionName()` syntax to call the function, not when you save `value.functionName` as a value somewhere. In that case, it just saves the function without any context.